# How do I change the functionality of the built in Array class in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am writing code in Ruby.
Say I have an array like this:

```
myarray = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to change the code of the Array class so that myarray[7] would return "out of bounds" instead of nil.

I don't want to make so that I check if something is out of bounds and then return "out of bounds", I want to implement this in Array directly.

Is this possible? Do I have to extend the Array class?

I'm Not sure how to start, very new to ruby. My initial thoughts were overriding a method in the Array class, but I'm not sure how to do that when I don't know what method is being used in myarray[i].

Comment: You probably meant `[]` instead of `{}`. Regarding your query, do you have a practical reason for doing this or is it idle curiosity? I'd not mess with the default behavior of the array unless you have a good reason for it. This can introduce some extremely bizarre bugs and make your code more surprising for people trying to read and contribute to it.

Comment: This is for a homework assigment. We have to add and change many default methods, this example is one I made up so that I can understand the process of modifying Array.

Comment: Well, `class Array; def [](i); "break Ruby here"; end; end` and off you go... Are you sure you're not supposed to subclass `Array`?

Comment: to expand on @ggorlen's commment - that would work but you would want to check if `i` is out of bounds there, you can do that by comparing it to the list length

Comment: IMO changing the behavior of a built-in method of a core class like `Array` is extremely dangerous and error-prone. Very likely other built-in methods depend on the original behavior and will break when the changed method returns unexpected results.

Comment: As a reading assignment, you might consider [Metaprogramming Ruby 2](https://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2/) by Paolo Perrotta. It's definitely an expert-level book, and covers topics like this in detail. It can be hard to digest for new Rubyists, but is a solid resource for a complex topic. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Let's start by examining the doc [Array#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D). As seen, that method can have a single integer argument:

```
arr[2]      #=> 3 
arr[-2]     #=> 4 
arr[5]      #=> nil 
arr[-7]     #=> nil 
arr['x']    #=> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)
```

or it may have two integer arguments:

```
arr[1,3]    #=> [2, 3, 4] 
arr[-3,2]   #=> [3, 4] 
arr[3,5]    #=> [4, 5] 
arr[7,4]    #=> nil 
arr[2,'x']  #=> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)
```

or it may have a range of integers as an argument:

```
arr[1..3]   #=> [2, 3, 4] 
arr[1...3]  #=> [2, 3] 
arr[-5..-2] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
arr[3..9]   #=> [4, 5] 
arr[7..10]  #=> nil 
arr[1..'x'] #=> ArgumentError (bad value for range)
```

As I understand, you wish to alter `Array#[]` in such way that its behavior is unchanged except for the case when its argument is a single integer representing an offset into the array that is out-of-bounds.<sup>1</sup>. That could be done by writing the method in a module and then *prepend* that module to the class `Array` with the method [Module#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend).

```
module NewSlice
  def [](*args)
    arg1, arg2 = args
    if arg2.nil? && arg1.is_a?(Integer) &&
      (arg1 > self.size-1 || arg1 < -self.size)
      "out of range"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

```
Array.prepend(NewSlice)
```

```
arr[2]      #=> 3 
arr[-2]     #=> 4 
arr[5]      #=> "out of range" 
arr[-7]     #=> "out of range"
arr['x']    #=> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)
```

```
arr[1,3]    #=> [2, 3, 4] 
arr[-3,2]   #=> [3, 4] 
arr[3,5]    #=> [4, 5] 
arr[7,4]    #=> nil   
arr[2,'x']  #=> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)
```

```
arr[1..3]   #=> [2, 3, 4] 
arr[1...3]  #=> [2, 3] 
arr[-5..-2] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
arr[3..9]   #=> [4, 5] 
arr[7..10]  #=> nil 
arr[1..'x'] #=> ArgumentError (bad value for range)
```

We see that

```
Array.ancestors
  #=> [NewSlice, Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

showing that `super` in `NewSlice#[]` calls the original method `Array#[]` after `NewSlice` has been prepended to `Array`. Since `super` has no arguments all the arguments that were passed to the new `Array#[]` method ( defined in `NewSlice`) are passed to the original `Array#[]`.

Aliases were commonly used in Ruby prior to the introduction of `Module#prepend` in Ruby v2.0. They are still used but their importance has diminished greatly since `prepend` has become available.

---

If `nil` is to be replaced by `"out of bounds"` in all cases where `Array#[]` returns `nil`, write

```
module NewSlice
  def [](*args)
    super || "out of bounds"
  end
end
```

```
Array.prepend(NewSlice)
```

```
arr[5]      #=> "out of range" 
arr[-7]     #=> "out of range"
arr[7,4]    #=> "out of range"   
arr[7..10]  #=> "out of range"
```

<sup>1. Whether it is advisable to modify core methods such as `Array#[]` is a separate question, but it can result in pain and suffering.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

This is an interesting question about how to monkeypatch core Ruby classes like Array. However, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that it involves some hijinks that seem unnecessary, since you could get the same behavior with a simple logical OR operator like:

```
[1, 2, 3][5] || 'out of bounds'
#=> "out of bounds"
```

Still, if you want to change the behavior of a core class then it can certainly be done.

### Re-Open the Core Class

In Ruby, almost everything that isn't a keyword is a method. Pragmatically, [Array::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is really just a method for indexing into an array object, with a little syntactic sugar from the interpreter to allow its arguments to be placed *inside* the brackets. Because it's just an instance method defined by the Array class, it can be modified in various ways such as re-opening the core class to modify the method, or by creating a singleton method on the instance. The first is conceptually simpler, but singleton methods are probably the safest solution for real-world programming.

You can re-open the Array class and redefine `Array::[]` as follows:

```
class Array
  # save off a copy of the existing method; we still need it
  alias_method :'old_[]', :'[]' unless defined? Array::old_[]

  # pass all arguments to the old method, but return a string
  # when the result is falsey
  def [] *args
    send("old_[]", *args) || 'out of bounds'
  end
end
```

You can then demonstrate that it works like a regular Array, but with your expected behavior:

```
a = [10, 20, 30]

a[0]   #=> 10
a[0,2] #=> [10, 20]
a[100] #=> "out of bounds"
```

### Add a Singleton Method

While the code above works, it's just generally a bad idea to monkeypatch a core class like Array. If you don't want to encapsulate this behavior in a subclass (e.g. `class MyArray < Array`), then you should use [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) (using [Module#refine](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Module.html#method-i-refine)) or singleton methods like the following to reduce the scope of your changes. For example:

```
a = [10, 20, 30]

class << a
  alias_method :'old_[]', :'[]' unless self.respond_to? 'old_[]'

  def [] *args
    send("old_[]", *args) || 'out of bounds'
  end
end
```

By limiting the scope of our change to a single instance, we're much less likely to cause serious or unrecoverable problems with core classes. A lot of things can go wrong in a Ruby program if a core class like Array starts returning truthy values (e.g. a String value such as `out of bounds`) rather than a falsey value like `nil`, so *caveat emptor!*

Comment: Note that if `Array#[]` is redefined as you suggest `[1,2,3][5,7] #=> "out of bounds"` and `[1,2,3][4..7] #=> "out of bounds"`. The OP may want those results but has not asked for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to break existing code (standard classes and ruin even methods of the current Array class itself, which rely on the current behaviour), you can of course monkeypatch it - open it and redefine the method in any way you like, as has been outlined in various answers to this question.

A more sane approach would be to subclass Array, i.e.

```
class BoundCheckingArray < Array
   # redefined the methods according to your taste.
end
```

Of course this would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Another approach will be to define a complete separate class and use [Delegator](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) to avoid rewriting everything from scratch, by delegating methods you did not rewrite explicitly, to the underlying array.

In both cases you need to be aware, that those methods in your BoundCheckingArray, which you did not explicitly rewrite and hence are taken from BoundCheckingArray, will stop working, if they assume that they can safely access the array outside of the bounds.

Another possibility would be to not modify existing Array methods, but simply add bound checking setters and getters, i.e. with monkeypatching:

```
class Array
  def at_checked(i)
    fail "out_of_bounds" if i >= size || i < -size
    at(i)
  end
  def set_checked(i, new_value)
    # analoguous
  end
end
```

Of course this approach would also work with subclassing (now adhering to Liskov's principle, because you just added methods) and delegating. Note that I coped explicitly with negative index values, assuming that you would like to use this feature in your bound checking array too.

Answer (score 0):

You may know classes in Ruby are defined like:

```rb
class Foo
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

Foo.new.foo # calls instance method `foo` on the instance of `Foo`
# => 'foo'
```

Classes and modules in Ruby can be "reopened" for re-definition (although it's a bit frowned upon -- makes it difficult to track code b/c code can be in either/any place):

```rb
class Foo
  def bar
    'bar'
  end

  def foo
    'overwrite foo'
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar
# => 'bar'

f.foo
# => 'overwrite foo'
```

This means you can also do:

```rb
class Array
  # re-define anything you want
end

# alternatively:
Array.class_eval do
  # the same as the above, in most ways
end
```

Even though it's even *less* recommended to modify existing methods of core Ruby classes. Not only does it break assumptions other Ruby developers may have of the code (i.e. misleading code), its global effect will likely break behaviors in other libraries, etc.